# Showing n numbers of a range that are prime numbers

Tags: java, android

I want to show in a `TextView` the prime numbers inside a range of numbers that I have defined previously, code:

```
private void primos() {
        int i, j;
        boolean esPrimo;
        int rInicial = 2;//Rango inicial
        int rFinal = 200;//Rango final
        for (i = rInicial; i <= rFinal; i++) {
            esPrimo = true;
            for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
                if (i % j == 0) {
                    esPrimo = false;
                }
            }
            if (esPrimo) {
               //No idea what to do here
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to continue the program to fill a `String` with the numbers and show it in my `TextView`. I think I have to cast in my `onCreate` and use the `findViewById`, but.. should I return an `Array` or `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a `String` to append all the answers you are having and display it in your `TextView`

```
private String primos() {
    int i, j;
    boolean esPrimo;
    int rInicial = 2;//Rango inicial
    int rFinal = 200;//Rango final
    String primeSeries = "";
    for (i = rInicial; i <= rFinal; i++) {
        esPrimo = true;
        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                esPrimo = false;
            }
        }
        if (esPrimo) {
           primeSeries += i + ", ";
        }
    }
    return primeSeries;
}
```

and while calling the `primos()` function do it this way

```
textView.setText(primos());
```

Comment: It should be  textView.setText(primos()); instead.

Comment: Now I understand what I was missing, but now in my onCreate when I do nameofmytextview.setText(primos()); it just throws a nullpointer, am I missing something here?

Comment: @Pablo may be you are missing initialization of nameofmytextview before setting the text

Comment: have you changed the return datatype of your function to String

Comment: Yes, I added a comment and forget about it, thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you'll want to separate your code into a few more methods for better organization. My version is very inefficient and is there simply to setup the code. You should look at some stuff for Sieve of Eratosthenes:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

```
private void primos() {
    int i, j;
    boolean esPrimo;
    int rInicial = 2;//Rango inicial
    int rFinal = 200;//Rango final
    String build = "";
    TextView myView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myid); //R.id.myid needs to be set by you
    for (i = rInicial; i <= rFinal; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)){
            build += i + " "; //however you want to display them
        }
    }
    myView.setText(build);
}

public boolean isPrime(int n){
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
        if (n % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```